# Image Classifier with Tensorflow and Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, image-recognition

I'm trying to get an Image Classifier to work. So far the model does seem to work but now every time I want to test an image to see if it is being recognized appropriately I have to do the whole training all over. I'm very new to this but I suppose there should be another way to only test the images without the training right?

I also have one further question concerning the code itself.

```
if result [0][0] >= 0.5:
    prediction = "cogwheel"
else:
    prediction = "not a cogwheel"
print(prediction)
```

I am trying to differentiate between images that represent cogwheels and those that don't. I understand that if the probability is > 0,5 it is a cogwheel and else it is not. But what does [0][0] here mean?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Keras allows you to save the results of trained models and load them again later, I suggest reading the documentation. As for your second question, that's a more general Python question. Have you taken a look at what data type `result` actually is?

Comment: How do you get `result`?

Comment: I get result by using result = classifier.predict(sample).
@AdmiralWen I should read up on the documentation yes, I pretty much stumbled into that whole topic with little to no prior knowledge of tensorflow and only some of python

Answer (score 5):

Since you are a beginner, you may not know that you actually do not need to retrain the model in order to test :D. Your hunch is right, and we will see down below how you can do that.

You can save the weights of your model in a specific file format. In Keras, it is a file with the extension .hdf5.

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model


##Do some stuff, train model

model.save(model_name)

##Do some stuff

loaded_model = load_model(model_name)
```

Please make sure that "model_name" includes .hdf5. For example, "my_model.hdf5".

Although it is not clear what you used to get the result (I assume result = model.predict(sample), where sample is a test sample), the first index corresponds to the class(label) and the second label corresponds to the probability of that specific class.

**Test to see result[0][0] (probability of class 0), result[1][0] (probability of class 1).**

Comment: So I can just add the saving part to the end of my code and it should save it as a .hdf5 file okay. But then do I need a new .py where I insert the loaded_model = load_model(model_name) part? When it comes to the second part I used "result = classifier.predict(sample). So I think I understand what you said there too, thank you!

Comment: Yes, you can add the loading model part in another script and test it there :D

Comment: No when I try to run this, I get the error message: NameError: name 'model' is not defined. Any idea why this might be the case?

Comment: Did you declare your model in the first place? What is the initial name of your model?

Comment: I cannot properly help you if I do not see any code written.

Comment: Sure sorry, so I really just added to print(prediction) (the last line of code from what I posted here in the first place):

from keras.models import load_model \n 
model.save("modelone.hdf5") \n 
del model \n 
model = load_model("modelone.hdf5")

Comment: I don't know how I would declare the model, that's not something that is usually being done in python right? There's not need to declare variables correct? And if by name of the model you mean the name of the .py, that doesn't work I'm afraid. I'm sorry I know those are really stupid questions I'm asking here but I just can't seem to find proper (for my level of understanding) documentation on what to do.